# Guitar tab symbol

Tags: notation, tablature, fingerstyle-guitar

Below are the first two measures from Adele's "Easy on Me".

[image: tabs for mm. 1–2]

What does the symbol on the top right of 2 mean in both the bars in the picture above?

Edit: Added the YouTube tutorial where the tabs are from. It seemed like a bend to me but is not really apparent to me in the video.

Answer (score 7):

Tim does surely have more expertise in this style of music, but I *suppose* this might be a notion of a tie. Both cases here are in place where a tie would make some sense, that is between the last 16th of beat 3 and the first of beat 4.

Comment: Yes, it’s a tie. In editions where there is both treble staff and tab, the treble staff would make it clear. Seems like someone copied that style and left out the treble staff. A better way to notate this in tab is with a fret number in parentheses on the later end of the tie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - please see my edit.

Comment: You may be right, as there's no number dedicated to the following note. However - that *could* also mean bend up, then let down again to that same (following) note. Not as clear as may be...  Particularly as there's *no* tie shown on the underneath dots. The plot thickens!

Comment: The performance in the video that has been added to the question confirms it's a tie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that doesn't explain the poor representation shown in the accompanying dots.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it's what I call the notes themselves. O.k., there are no actual dots, but surely it could make sense. Call them stems if you like!

Comment: Even if the author meant this as a tie it is inconsistent and doesn't seem to mean anything specific as the whole sequence is played as "let ring" and there's many other places here where the notes should be prolonged in a same way

Answer (score 1):

It's a bend - upwards. Not so prevalent these days, as it doesn't tell how much of a bend to use. But given the semis that are displayed (a good move, as a lot of tab doesn't reveal timing), it's going to be quite a quick slurp on that note, before playing the next.

EDIT: it is actually an old symbol for bend, but looking at the dots underneath reveals no number for the following semiquaver. Which, I guess, means that note isn't played again. So, no need for a tie, although an indication of how much bend would be useful. Instead, bend up, let down. However, in my defence, there really ought to be a tie (or slur...) marked on those dots underneath, making it far more clear! So much clearer with 'proper' dots accompanying the tab, though.

RE-EDIT - *now*, having listened to both the tutorial, and more importantly, the original, it's obviously *not* a bend. It's simply a tie, across the beat. However, that's just not reflected in the dots shown below, which now are deemed (by me) to be inaccurate. And, a tie sign *could* have been used (for both), which would have made the question redundant!